# Spark : How to speedup foreachRDD?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a Spark streaming application which ingests data **@10,000/ sec** ... We use the foreachRDD operation on our DStream( since spark doesn't execute unless it finds the output operation on DStream)

so we have to use the foreachRDD output operation like this , it takes upto to **3 hours** ...to write a singlebatch of data (10,000) which is **slow**

**CodeSnippet 1:**

```
requestsWithState.foreachRDD { rdd =>

     rdd.foreach {
     case (topicsTableName, hashKeyTemp, attributeValueUpdate) => {          
          val client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient()
          val request = new UpdateItemRequest(topicsTableName, hashKeyTemp, attributeValueUpdate)
          try client.updateItem(request)

        catch {
            case se: Exception => println("Error executing updateItem!\nTable ", se)
         }
        }
        case null =>
      }
    }
  }
```

So i thought the code inside foreachRDD might be the problem so commented it out to see how much time it takes ....**to my surprise ...even with nocode inside the foreachRDD it still run's for 3 hours**

**CodeSnippet 2:**

```
requestsWithState.foreachRDD { 
rdd => rdd.foreach { 
// No code here still takes a lot of time ( there used to be code but removed it to see if it's any faster without code) // 
 }
}
```

Please let us know if we are missing anything or an alternative way to do this as i understand without a output operation on DStream spark streaming application will not run .. at this time i can't use other output operations ...

**Note : To isolate the problem and make sure that dynamo code is not problem ...i ran with empty loop .....look's like foreachRDD is slow on it's own when iterating over a huge record set coming in @10,000/sec ...and not the dynamo code as empty foreachRDD and with dynamo code took the same time ...**

ScreenShot showing all the stages that are executed and time taken by **foreachRDD** even though it's jus looping and no code inside

**Time taken by the foreachRDD empty loop**

[image: **Time taken by the foreachRDD empty loop**]

**Task distribution for large running task among 9 worker nodes for the foreachRDD empty loop  ...**

[image: **Task Distribution among 9 worker nodes for the foreachRDD empty loop**]

Comment: Not sure about why the empty one would be slow, but make sure your write throughput to dynamo is insanely high, if you have a lot of clusters running this at one time. Might be helpful to post your spark streaming configuration as well.

Comment: @Derek_M thanks for your comment ....we have insanely huge numbers for read and write throughput ...writing 10,000 should not be an issue .......like i mentioned in the question ..dynamo code should not be an issue  and to prove that it's not an issue i ran with empty loop ...and looks like foreachRDD is slow on it's own ....

Comment: What does your streaming config look like? Are you doing any additional operations before you run foreachRDD?

Comment: @Derek_M i do run map transformations but as u can see ..from the updated screen shot ..that they are only taking few second's the major time in minutes is taken by foreachRDD empty loop..

Comment: Please share the complete code , I mean the type of stream, and batch interval .. Also try running the job with log level INFO/DEBUG to see what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Is `requestsWithState` literally "with-state" (like `mapWIthState` upstream?). If the answer is positive then every data skew will hit your performance. Can you show task runtime distribution for a job with high duration?

Comment: @zero323  yes you are absolutely right in your assumption that it has a mapWithState in upstream .......i have updated the question with the task distribution ....please let me know if u need more info

Comment: Please show the task details of the slow stage.

Comment: @zsxwing i have added the task details to the question please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Can you share some insights on how this issue was solved? We are also facing tremendous performance issues while using foreachPartition

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late,but if you like to hear,I have some guess that may give you some insights.

It is not the code inside `rdd.foreach` that takes long time,but the code before `rdd.foreach`, the code which generate the rdd.
Transformations are lazy,spark does not compute it until you use the result.
When code runs in `rdd.foreach`,spark do the computation,and generate the data rows.The code in rdd.foreach loops only manipulate the result.
You can check this by commenting out the rdd.foreach

```
requestsWithState.foreachRDD { 
  //rdd => rdd.foreach { 
  // No code here still takes a lot of time ( there used to be code but removed it to //see if it's any faster without code) 
  //}
}
```

I guess it will be extremely fast,because no computations happens.
Or you can change the transformations to a very simple one,it will be fast too.
It does not solve your problem,but if I'm right,it will help you locate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with no loop, like below?

```
//requestsWithState.foreachRDD {  
  //rdd => rdd.foreach {  
  // No code here //  
  // } 
//}
```

It's the `foreachRDD` which is taking time not the code inside it. Please note that it is `foreach` not `for`. It will run `n` times whether there is code inside it or not.

Effective tests can be used for performance testing:

https://tech.ovoenergy.com/spark-streaming-in-production-testing/