# Spark : RDD action to be triggerd for DStream to be processed

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

As per the spark documention as per the link here

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#other-points-to-remember

"DStreams are executed lazily by the output operations, just like RDDs are lazily executed by RDD actions. Specifically, RDD actions inside the DStream output operations force the processing of the received data. Hence, if your application does not have any output operation, or has output operations like dstream.foreachRDD() without any RDD action inside them, then nothing will get executed. The system will simply receive the data and discard it."

We have a spark streaming application with map operation followed by the DStream output operation As pert the documentation we have a RDD action inside **foreachRDD** which is **rdd.first()** but still nothing happen's

```
tempRequestsWithState is DStream 

tempRequestsWithState.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    rdd.first()

  }
```

but interestingly if we do **rdd.foreach** inside foreachRDD application run's perfectly ....

```
tempRequestsWithState.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    rdd.foreach {

    }
  }
```

**In our case rdd.foreach  is a very slow operation and would like to avoid it as we are dealing with huge data load of 10,000 events/sec also we need the foreachRDD ..**

Please let us know if we are missing anything and if we can try any other RDD action inside foreachRDD

Comment: If you don't have any output action what exactly do you expect to be processed (it sounds like you're depending on some side effect upstream and this is a very bad idea)? There is nothing inherently slow in `foreach` - it just evaluates, unlike `first`, all records. If upstream process is expensive and / or you have not enough resources it will be slow. Remember that for example `mapWithState` (I assume this is [the same case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42582542/1560062)) requires full shuffle and is quite expensive.

Comment: @zero323 as per the documentation my understanding is any RDD action inside  foreachRDD should process data ....first() is an action...of an RDD if i understand so why does it not allow data to be processed why does ..foreach...allows data to be processed

Comment: `first` consumes as much data as it is required to obtain a single output record. It may be a single input item (if there is no shuffle upstream) or more items (if there is a shuffle upstream). It doesn't guarantee that every record will be processed. One way or another lack of "real" output action smells.

Comment: There is lack of output operation ..because ...i want to see if foreachRDD is inherently slow ......and not the code inside foreachRDD...

Comment: Like I said, there is nothing inherently slow in `foreach` / `foreachRDD`. If you need a minimal action you can `foreachRDD(_.foreach(_ => ()))` - it won't get cheaper than this :)

Comment: yep but that's what i i did here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582542/spark-how-to-speedup-foreachrdd ...and i posted image how much time even that is taking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137241/discussion-between-user2359997-and-zero323).

Comment: to update on the chat discussion ....i'm still looking for answer for this question ...any help will be greatly appreciated